# Getting error in merging two data set using cbind R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app and want to merge this two files which I have converted in numeric form.

See my code below:

```
 g_t1 <-reactive({ 
subset(merge_cli_mi(),select=c(er,t))
})
 g_t2 <-reactive({ lapply(g_t1(),as.factor) 
})
g_t3 <-reactive({ lapply(g_t2(),as.numeric) 
})

output$t1<-renderTable({
 g_t3()
})



g_t11 <-reactive({ 
subset(merge_cli_mi(),select=-c(er,t))
})
g_t21 <-reactive({ lapply(g_t11(),as.factor) 
})
g_t31 <-reactive({ lapply(g_t11(),as.numeric) 
})

output$t11<-renderTable({
            g_t31()
})


merge_cli_mi_gt13<-reactive({
cbind(g_t31(),g_t3())    

}) 
output$merge_cli_mi13<-renderTable({
merge_cli_mi_gt13()
})
```

But while execution I got an error saying " 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".
I don't know why I am getting this error. How can I solve and merge both data frames?

Comment: Hi please share some data via ```dput()``` . and make sure while merging same column name is there in both the data frame.

Comment: maybe its not necessary both data frame should have same column name